# mysql order by alphabet and set "other" to the end

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the table 'category' with two columns: 'id' and 'name'.

I Want to display the names and order the table by alphabet, but if the name "other" is present, i want to set it to be the last row.

Is there a way to achieve this without creating another column that marks the position?

```
ORDER BY name DESC { something to set name = "other" to the end }
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `CASE`, you can apply ordering conditionally in the `ORDER BY`.  Rows where `name <> 'other'` are conditionally assigned a `0` which sorts ahead of those matching `other` which are assigned a `1`. Then it is sub-ordered by `name`.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name <> 'other' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  name ASC
```

You use `name DESC` in your example, but your description implies you want it sorted in ascending alphabetical order. If that is incorrect and you *do* want it descending, use `name DESC` instead.

Note that for MySQL, the boolean expression `(name = 'other')` will evaluate to a 0 or 1. So this can be simplified to omit the `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY
  /* name <> 'other' returns 0 */
  (name = 'other'),
  name ASC
```

This is not portable to any RDBMS though.

Comment: "Use an `ORDER BY CASE` construct" -- this may be **VERY CONFUSING** to newbies. And give them wrong point that there is a constuct `ORDER BY CASE`

Comment: @zerkms Description completed.

Comment: I was talking about exact "Use an ORDER BY CASE construct" phrase, which is just not correct. I'd explained about `ORDER BY` and `CASE` differently

Comment: @zerkms Better? "`ORDER BY CASE` construct" must not be as widely used a term as I expect.

Comment: great, just wat i was looking for. Thanks. Ill mark it as accepted after the timer lets me.

Comment: Wouldn't that slow a query down extremely? what are the thoughts about a union with one query excluding 'other' and another query fetching 'other' exclusively? Union could be ordered by orderDummy, name

Comment: @MichelFeldheim It is worth benchmarking.  Consider that the `name` column would also need to be indexed in order to filter both sides of the `UNION` in a `WHERE` clause quickly. The `ORDER BY` may be able to make use of the same index.